# Are these sake and strawberry flavored Kit Kats?

Tags: translation, adjectives

I want to say (as a caption to a picture "are these sake and strawberry flavored Kit Kats?  Yes, they are!"　The picture has two small Kit Kats, one of each flavor, if that matters.

I've come up with 「これは日本酒とイチゴ風味のキットカットですか。はい！」

The "sake and strawberry flavored Kit Kat" is mostly a literal translation from English, so I'm fairly sure I'm missing some nuances there.  It seems like there's also a few different ways to say flavor, so I picked one that looked like it fit best from Jisho.org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「日本酒風味にイチゴ風味のキットカット！？」「そうよ！」 sounds more natural, if you use this phrase as a caption to a picture.

Comment: Well, its going to be a facebook post with a picture.  :-)  It's more natural because those parts would normally be omitted?  I did notice you also replaced the と with a に.  Is と incorrect?  How does に change the understanding?

Comment: 'に' means 'in addition to', while 'と' means 'and'. i.e. 'に' has some effect of  emphasizing.

Comment: What is emphasized exactly?  Does it imply one kitkat which two flavors or two different bars with one flavor each?

Comment: It implies that the person is surprised to hear such kinds of flavors exist.

Answer (score 1):

The following is the perfect translation. I'm afraid but there is no
senistive nuance about the sentence.

"Are these sake and strawberry flavored Kit Kats? Yes, they are!" = 「これは日本酒とイチゴ風味のキットカットですか。はいそうです！」

By the way, there are two types of flavored Kit Kats. One is sake flavored one, and the other is strawberry flavored one. There is no mixed sake and strawberry flavored one.

Comment: Right, its not mixed, its two wrapped Kit Kats, one of each flavor.